# Multi Transistor Circuit

Tags: transistors, transistor-array

I made a multistage transistor circuit to see, with such a high gain, what the output would be?

[image]
(Bottom Terminal to +5V, Top Right Terminal to Gnd)

I've seen circuits with three transistors in this fashion, being used to detect an AC source nearby. The base of the first transistor is connected to an antenna sort of structure and when bought near AC source, the LED turns ON. So I  thought to add more stages to see what else it can do?

I expected that it may detect the RF communication signals or it may detect any AC source from much larger distances(I guess I was expecting miracle out of a random built) . But it showed wierd behavior. When powered, it would turned the light ON and when any part of the circuit is touched with a finger the light turns off. And after releasing the finger, the light slowly-slowly rises to its maximum brightness again, until it is touched again.

When it does not behave like just described, it behaves like this:
When I move close to the circuit light intensity increases and when I move away it decreases.

I have vague idea that it may have something to do with the capacitance between me and the circuit, but I don't understand how exactly it work out for this circuit? Is this phenomenon well known and is this thing studied under any subject?

Comment: nice sculpture ... please post the schematic diagram

Comment: have you tried attaching a long wire to the LED without any transistors or resistors?

Comment: I like it because I did someting like then when I was 11. Started with one NPN, then two then three. Stopped there because just moving my hand NEAR the floating base would set the light bulb off. (No LEDS in those days)

Comment: Interesting... It reminds me a Darlington transistor with many nested (like Russian dolls) transistors...

Comment: It gives new meaning to "dead bug construction."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electromagnetic Fields with free space impedance allows one to capture a tiny bit of current from your body acting as a dielectric antenna with some impedance to the amplified semiconductor switch to the LED.

What comes out would be a half wave rectified pulse of light from the radiated low frequency grid voltage electric field in V/m.

Putting another finger in the middle could be shunting the Vbe to cutoff.

Electric field from a line in the wall will be somewhat inverse to distance and proportional to length of you and conductor as an antenna.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1dtxj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

maybe something like this